# Change the names of the tabs in excel from ssrs

Tags: excel, reporting-services, tabs, ssrs-tablix

I have an ssrs that contains some tables in seperated sheets in excel.
When one report is empty, the tab take the name from the previous tab.

The names are daclared in the tablix properties in 'PageName'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a page break at start for all matrices except the first one.

If you want to avoid empty sheets, set the matrix visibility expression to something like

`= CountRows("DataSet2")=0`

Comment: Thanks for answer, But the table still takes up space, even though it's hidden, How I can avoide it?

Comment: Hiding the matrix when there are no rows for the dataset seems not taking any space. Can you provide more details or an image?

Comment: You're right, that was another mistake. Thanks.