# SSRS Report Incorrectly Naming Excel Tab

Tags: excel, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using MS SQL Server 2014 Report Builder 3.0 to generate an SSRS report in Excel.  The SSRS report contains 3 sup-reports driven by independent matrices.  I'm using page breaks to separate each of these into their own Excel tabs called Detail, Summary and Audit in that order.  The "Audit" sub-report will often be blank, which is completely expected.  The problem is that when this occurs, the Excel workbook will be generated with "Audit" tab instead being named "Detail2".

I've tried switching between placing the page breaks after "Summary" and "Detail" to placing the page breaks before "Detail" and "Audit" and it's the same issue either way.

Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68080920/change-the-names-of-the-tabs-in-excel-from-ssrs/68081276#68081276

Answer (score 0):

Use a Rectangle and place the subreport inside of it. Then set the page name of the Rectangle.

[image]

[image]